# Formal alternative/synonyme of "quand même"?

Tags: usage, synonymes

What is the other way to say quand​ même?
Once, one said to me that I shouldn't use it if I want to write a report, or any formal paper.

Especially in this kind of context:

> "On vérifie ensuite, qu'il puisse quand même envoyer bla bla . . . "

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry but the sentence "On vérifie ensuite, est-ce qu'il puisse quand-même envoyer..." just does not make sense  Did you mean "We'll check later. Can he (still) send it out?" ?

Comment: @SteffX I wanted to say "We'll verify later, Is he still be able to send bla bla bla".

Comment: @Nathan aha, damn auto-correct. Exacty what I wanted to say, thanks

Comment: May I also point out that "quand même" should not have a hyphen between "quand" and "même" ?

Comment: @greg I have no idea which one is the correct one :D

Comment: It is definitely "quand même", but it is a mistake that even native speakers will sometimes do. I guess that is because "lui-même", "moi-même", etc, do require a hyphen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  "**tout de même**", which can be translated as "anyway". Depending of the context, you could also use "de toute facon".

Example:

> C'est compliqué? On fait ça quand même.

is equal to

> C'est compliqué? On fait ça de toute façon/ tout de même.

Answer (score 2):

Selon le site Le Bon Synonyme, on trouve [quatre synonymes de "quand même"](https://lebonsynonyme.fr/synonyme/quand-m%C3%AAme) :

- Tout de même
- De toute façon
- Aussi
- Dans tous les cas